# How to scale image in high quality and draw it to canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I have a PNG image in app's resources, that has 950*291 pixels, placed in `drawable-mdpi` directory. I want to create an in-memory `Bitmap`, where I want to draw it scaled down (actually 100 pixels high). I tried many ways, but it looks pixelated.

I tried the following:

1. Load it as `BitmapDrawable`, enabled `AntiAlias` and `FilterBitmap` and called it's `draw` method.
2. Load it using `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` with `opts.inScaled` set to fales and drawn to canvas using `Matrix`.
3. Same as previous, but first scaled it down using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` and then drawing to canvas without a matrix.

Neither worked. This is the image I get, it is not smooth, is pixelated:

[image: Scaled down on Android with filterBitmap=true]

It seems that `Paint.setFilterBitmap` does have some effect, because without it it's even a bit worse:

[image: Scaled down on Android with filterBitmap=false]

This is the scaled down version using just any image editor using the same original image, which is a lot smoother.

[image: Scaled down with image editor]

Am I not able to scale images in higher quality with Android? The image clearly stands out to other antialiased text in the image.

This is my current code:

```
// create in-memory bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1000, 1100, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
bitmap.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);

// load the original image
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inScaled = false;
opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
Bitmap logoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.main_logo, opts);
logoBitmap.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);

// scale it down and draw it
Bitmap scaledLogo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(logoBitmap, logoWidth, logoHeight, false);
canvas.drawBitmap(scaledLogo, x, y, paint);
```

Tested on Android 5.0. I worked it around by adding scaled version to resources, but want to know what was wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to use `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` instead of `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` ?

Comment: `This is the scaled down version using just any image editor using the same original image,` which is why you should provide your scaled images into several drawable folders. Or use SVG files (or even VectorDrawables).

Comment: I have tried, no luck. More precisely, I tried to load the `logoImage` with `ARGB_8888` config and to scale it using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` and saved that to file and the files are identical with the previous one.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi I know that, but it adds more resources to manage, larger APK, and what if the target size is not static? Answer the question.

Comment: `SVG` files, being vectorial, are (by definition) scalable. Therefore, you'd need only one resource and scale it as per your current screen size. `VectorDrawables`, being a *subset* of SVG files, are as well.

Comment: But: `VectorDrawables` are available only for android>5, which is prohibitive. SVGs are, AFAIK, supported only as a third party build plugin, which generates PNG files in all resolutions during build, so no scaling at runtime.

Comment: **Wrong**. And **wrong**. `VectorDrawables` are available to the older API levels through the **support library**. `SVG` files (yes, by using a FREE library) will be scaled **at runtime** and generate a BitmapDrawable to be inserted into your Views.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi could hou point me to the support libray? I've only found unofficial supported for api14+ and some work-in-progress for official support library. Also could not find support for SVG.

Comment: SVG files are not supported through any API library, yet (hopefully they'll replace VectorDrawables with SVGDrawables?). Only by 3rd party free libraries, like android-svg and svg-andoid.

Comment: And VectorDrawables?

Comment: I was wrong about those ones. The ones will work as you said: Android Studio will convert them to PNGs for older APIs. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32908702/2649012

Comment: Ok, so we are back, nothing new here. If you know, answer the question :).