# Which third-party dependencies are declared in the build.gradle of this Android Studio project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, build.gradle, support-vector-compat

I want to convert [this Android Studio project](https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat) into an Eclipse project.

The way to do it is to copy everything in all src packages and res directory from AS project to Eclipse project, and change the Eclipse project's Manifest file by adding all the additional elements from AS project.

**The catch is** that I have to do this for all the third party dependencies (declared in build.gradle) on which the AS project depends and then add those library projects to this newly created Eclipse project.

Normally I would do it for each library listed in the `dependencies` section of build.gradle file of AS project. But for [this library project](https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat/blob/master/library/build.gradle), I don't understand what are the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
}
```

**I don't understand the first and third line. Please tell me which libraries are declared in first and third line, so that I can copy those projects in Eclipse?**

---

***EDIT:***

Here is the output of `gradlew.bat -q dependencies` command:

[image]

---

***EDIT 1:***

[image]

---

***EDIT 2:***

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each project module, do the following from the command line:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies
```

This will print out a graph of all dependencies the module has.

Comment: `from the command line:` - the normal windows cmd program?  I have never run Java programs from commandline

Comment: Yes. On Windows you would call gradlew.bat instead of ./gradlew, given that you're using Gradle wrapper.

Comment: I entered `D:\Delight\Workspaces\Workspace of Libraries\vector-compat-master\library>gradlew.bat -q dependencies`, and got **`'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. `**

Comment: Normally gradlew.bat is located in the project directory, one level above the modules directory, so you have to point to it. I'm not sure how it's done on Windows, on Mac it would be ../gradlew instead of ./gradlew.

Comment: OK I found gradlew.bat. I have posted a screenshot of the output of the command in the question. It says, "No Configurations". Does this mean there are no dependencies? In the build.gradle file, I can see at least one Appcompat_v22 dependency. :s

Comment: Looks like you're running the task on the root project, while you should run it on the module. You can use the following instead: gradlew.bat -q :<module-name>:dependencies, substitute <module-name> with the real name of the module.

Comment: Actually I am not aware of project structure in Android Studio, so don't know where to find all the modules. Could you look [here](https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat) and tell me the name of the module? (The library is in the `library` directory.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117811/discussion-between-egor-and-solace).